# count number of lines from dat file and exit accordingly using batch script

Tags: batch-file, scripting

I am new to batch scripting. 
I need to count number of lines from a dat file and should throw failure if count is less than or equal to 2. If count is 3 or greater script should return success.

I tried the below code but prompt isn't responding as expected.

```
findstr /R /N "^" filename.DAT | find /C":" > test.txt
SET /p count=<test.txt
 IF %count% leq "2" 
(exit 1)
else (exit 0)
pause
```

Comment: It's worth pointing out that a file with the `.dat` extension may contain binary data, or for the purposes of solutions may not contain standard printable text and control characters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

using quotes forces `if` to compare strings. So it compares string `2` with string `"2"` - clearly not a match... Use a better approach (without a temporary file):

```
for /f %%a in ('^<filename.dat find /v /c ""') do set /a count=%%a
if %count% leq 2 (exit 1) else (exit 0)
```

Note: when you should try to use `if "%count%" leq "2"`, remember, you are comparing strings. So `100` is *lower* than `2`.

Comment: I believe you need to use (escaped) redirection `^< "filename.dat"` (due to `for /F`) in order to avoid a header with file name to be included in the output...

Comment: can i use regex in place of filename.dat? for eg- "file*.dat"

Comment: no, not even wildcards are possible with redirection. What's your intention? This code would `exit` anyways after the first matching file.

Comment: File name will be dynamic. I can specify only a pattern of the file. How can i make it accept a pattern?

Comment: File name will be filename_YYYYMMDD.dat. Current date. how can i modyf this script to pick current date at end of filename

Comment: I got it. Using the below , file%date:~-4,4%%date:~-7,2%%date:~-10,2%.DAT